# How can I draw a gradient using directFB in a Qt application?

Tags: qt, graphics, qt4, gradient

I want to create a Qt application, supported by [directFB](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qt-embeddedlinux-directfb.html#directfb-driver), and I need to paint gradients in the application. However I understand that gradients are not supported graphics operations with directFB.

My question is, how can I create a gradient in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The gradient painting is supported by the raster engine, and it will surely work. Just try it.